# Marginal Pdfs for Continuous Random Variables

Tags: probability, statistics, functions, random-variables

http://oi42.tinypic.com/ddyjph.jpg
this problem is confusing me, i know how to start it, we need to find $f_Y(y)$ so we integrate with respect to x and i get $-2e^{-x}e^{-y}|^y_0$ which then should come out to $-2e^{-y}e^{-y}$ however the answer in the book is coming out to $2e^{-y}-2e^{-2y}, 0≤y$. can someone please explain why that is

Comment: $$-2e^{-x}e^{-y}\biggr|_{x=0}^{x=y} = -2e^{-y}e^{-y} - (-2e^{-0}e^{-y}) = 2e^{-y}-2e^{-2y},$$ and not $=2e^{-y}e^{-y}$, no? Since you are self-admittedly not a math wiz, here is one thing that you should take to heart. Any time you get a purported pdf with a negative sign in front, you should get the heeby-jeebies, worry that something is awry, and check your work carefully instead of confidently asserting that your answer is correct. Now that you have learned that, show that $f(x) = -\ln x$, for $0 < x < 1$ and $0$ otherwise is a valid pdf.

Comment: Common error, to assume that at the lower limit $0$ a function is automatically $0$.

Comment: got it, thanks!